# image preview does not work in tramp for org mode

Tags: image, emacs, org-mode, tramp

Suppose I'm checking out a org file in a server `server1`,

```
(find-file "/ssh:server1:/path/to/org-file.org")
```

and the org file has a link to an image

```
file:myimage.png
```

and the file exists since I can open it with `C-c C-o`.
However, when I try to display the image, it does not work.

I see no reason why this shouldn't work.

[image: here is a screencast of the problem]

Comment: Consider filing a bug report.

Comment: would you guess in tramp or in org-mode, I'd say this is an org-mode side problem

Comment: I'd go for org-mode first.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with Org mode version 9.4.3 and Emacs 28.0.50 - what version of Org mode/Emacs are you running?

Comment: I'm using org-mode version 9.3.7 and emacs 26.3. However some friends runnning emacs 27 have reproduced this, I have reported to the org-mode mailing list, but I guess it'll take some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default this feature is disabled.

To enable it checkout the variable `org-display-remote-inline-image`.

For example, I set it with:

```lisp
  (setq org-display-remote-inline-images 'cache)
```